# Reduce the weight of webp

Tags: ffmpeg, webp, webm, mov

Im new to ffmpeg

I got webm (2.21mb) with alpha transparency and trying to convert it to animated webp also with alpha with that command:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm output.webp
```

Output webp gets 43.1mb.
So how I can reduce more weight from webp? What I need to add to my command?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-quality` output option specific to libwebp (the encoder ffmpeg uses to encode webp):

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm -quality 50 output.webp
```

From `ffmpeg -h encoder=libwebp`:

```
-quality <float>  
  Quality (from 0 to 100) (default 75)
```